# Can't insert elements into vector of list

Tags: c++, list, vector

I have a vector of list. Each vector element(which is a list in this case) stores numbers which have 1(in binary representation) at the same bit position as the index of the vector. i.e for 5, 0th and 2nd element(list) of vector will contain 5. But program terminates while trying to insert values to the vector of list. Vector's capacity remains 0 even after calling reserve() and resize(). how to do this correctly? Pls help! Here is the relevant code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
using namespace std;
void preprocess(int);
int test_case,x,y,monsters,queries;
int* health;
int to_change;
vector<list<int> > bits;
int main()
{
    cin>>test_case;
    while(test_case--)
    {
        cin>>monsters;
        health = new int[monsters];
        bits.resize(32);
        bits.reserve(32);
        for(int i=0;i<monsters;i++)
        {
            cin>>health[i];
            preprocess(health[i]);
        }
    }
}
void preprocess(int val)
{
    int a,this_bit,copy_of_health;
    cout<<"currently:"<<val<<endl;
    a=val,this_bit = 0,copy_of_health = a;
    while(a)
    {
            if(a&1==1)
            {
                cout<<"Working on val"<<endl;
                bits[this_bit].push_back(copy_of_health); //fails to execute this line
                cout<<"done upto this"<<endl;
                cout<<"This list size:"<<bits[this_bit].size()<<endl;
                cout<<"pushed"<<copy_of_health<<"successfully"<<"in bit position"<<this_bit<<endl;
            }
            this_bit++;
            a >>= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an `int*` and using it to allocate additional memory on each iteration. Every time you go around the loop, you leak `monsters * sizeof(int)` bytes. This makes the code confusing as it is difficult to tell what is intended since the underlying approach is incorrect.

Comment: There is no point in calling `reserve` after `resize`. A cleaner way is to use `push_back` instead of `resize` + assignment by index.

Comment: Aside:  If someone types 'x' for your monster count; you're going to have some bad times.

Comment: Why do you even want this vector of lists? If you wrote your goal more clearly, we would be able to maybe provide better solution than the one you want to achieve.

Comment: yeah actually there are some serious issues with my code. As you mentioned, it suffers of memory leak(I overlooked it and thanks for noticing), input validation, global variable issues. But my question is about the method preprocess() which fails to insert element into the lists inside vector. Actually there is no specific reason for using lists. It could also be done with vector inside vector. As I have written, what I want to do it is to store some numbers in such a way that every number having a 1 in same bit positions belong to same group. So, a number can be stored in multiple groups.

Answer (score 0):

error：vector subscript out of range!
since `the vector<list<int>> bits` can not be initialized by default;

```
list<int> l1,l2;//...
vector<list<int>> bits{l1,l2};//...
```

just make sure your vector has enough lists. ^-^

and i recommend using unique_ptr or shared_ptr (need a self-defined destructor) to manage your resource:

```
unique_ptr<int[]> health(new int[monsters]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :) Is there actually any other way to do it ?? because this one seems too lengthy. Like say can I use some loop ?

Comment: cout << "Working on val" << endl;
   list<int> il;
   bits.push_back(il);